# is it possible variable inhrit the my turtles label

Tags: netlogo

i want my variable to inherit the label of my turtles.

im making routes for them and want them to remember the last place they visited.

so theyll continue to the next place in the chain.

```
ifelse last_place = home 

[set place min-one-of (turtles with [label = "mall"])[distancemyself]]

[set place min-one-of (turtles with [label = "home"])[distancemyself]]
```

i cant use my actual code in here but hopefully, you get the gist

if

```
place = one-of turtles with [label = "mallI]
```

I want to add

set `last_place` label of place

i want `last_place` to get the label of place.

i know it can create loops if i have the same place twice in the same route but i want to create a list to prevent them but right now i need a sort of where flag that will make my turtles keep going to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing more of your code- it's hard to know what turtle is doing what. If your code is sensitive, I'd recommend following the tips in the [MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make a reproducible example- it might be easier to address your exact problem that way!

As an alternative, instead of using a label it's probably better to just have the turtles store the "location" turtle or patch in a turtle-variable. Using this simple example setup:

```
breed [ walkers walker ]
breed [ locations location ]

walkers-own [ location-list ]

to setup
  ca
  create-walkers 10 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set location-list []
    pd
  ]
  create-locations 20 [
    set size 1.5
    set shape "house"
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

You can have turtles store the places they visit in a list and reference them that way.

```
to go
  ask walkers [

    ; Build an agrentset of locations that do not belong 
    ; to each turtle's 'location-list'
    let unvisited-locations locations with [ 
      not member? self [location-list] of myself
    ]

    ; Target the nearest unvisited location
    let target min-one-of unvisited-locations [ distance myself ]

    ; if the target exists, move towards it
    if target != nobody [
      face target
      ifelse distance target > 1 [
        fd 1 
      ] [ 
        move-to target
        set location-list lput target location-list
      ]
    ]

    ; if a turtle visits all locations, remove the
    ; first location visited from the 'location-list'
    ; so that it will follow the same pattern continuously
    if length location-list = count locations [
      set location-list but-first location-list
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: to walk-towards
ask-civis
[ifelse waiting-time > 0]